# How to override the adminhtml template in magento 2 for a specific website in mutiwebsite functionality?

Tags: magento2.2, phtml, multi-website

I have created two website and need to override the adminhtml order view phtml only for the second website. Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OrderCustomiztion\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeDataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address;
class Info extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info{

/**
     * Customer service
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface
     */
    protected $metadata;

    /**
     * Group service
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $groupRepository;

    /**
     * Metadata element factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\ElementFactory
     */
    protected $_metadataElementFactory;

    /**
     * @var Address\Renderer
     */
    protected $addressRenderer;
    protected $_storeManager; 

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Helper\Admin $adminHelper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $metadata
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\ElementFactory $elementFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Sales\Helper\Admin $adminHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $metadata,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\ElementFactory $elementFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->metadata = $metadata;
        $this->_metadataElementFactory = $elementFactory;
        $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
        parent::__construct($context,$registry,$adminHelper,$groupRepository,$metadata,$elementFactory,$addressRenderer);
        $code= $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        if($code == "columbus_app_store_view"){
              $this->setTemplate('Amos_OrderCustomiztion::Info.phtml');
              echo '<pre>';print_r("hie");die();
        }
        else{
           echo '<pre>';print_r("hie2");die(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide location of that file

Comment: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Comment: @MeetaliGupta you can change template using xml layout also. check this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237179/magento-2-i-want-to-add-ifconfig-in-override-block-xml?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create new module
- Create a file at **Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
  <body>
      <referenceBlock name="order_info">
          <action method="setTemplate">
             <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
         </action>
     </referenceBlock>
  </body>
  ```
- Just copy **vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\info.phtml** to **Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\info.phtml**
- You need to override **Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info** for get the current website id.
- Now you can place condition according to your need in our info.phtml file

Answer (score 1):

If you have a block php file defined for that template, You can set template in block file.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    if(website1)
        $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::tpl1.phtml');
    else if(website2)
        $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::tpl2.phtml');
}
```

Comment: Yash shah- Its not working. Please see my updated code.

Comment: I think you have placed setTemplate in __construct instead of _construct ... That may be the issue .. try to place that code in _construct function. Let me know if it still doesnt work.